# Serializing Objects with Alamofire and bearer token

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, alamofire

Using the excellent Alamofire library v1.2, in a IOS 8, Xcode 6.3 and swift project, I'm trying to serialize objects from JSON-API response and I would like to know which is the best way to accomplish it. 
I think the main issues in the code below are:

- in the class controller, println(data) shows nil.
- in the Club Object
  Class, location property is not mapped correctly.

The JSON-API response is:

```js
hits = [{
  "_id" : "5470def9e0c0be27780121d7",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/5470def9e0c0be27780121d7_180.png",
  "name" : "Mondo",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f_180.png",
  "name" : "Teatro Kapital",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "Atocha, 125",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b_180.png",
  "name" : "Charada",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "La Bola, 13",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}]
```

Generic Response Collection Serialization:

```js
@objc public protocol ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    static func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Self]
}

extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseCollection<T: ResponseCollectionSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, [T]?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        let serializer: Serializer = { (request, response, data) in
            let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let (JSON: AnyObject?, serializationError) = JSONSerializer(request, response, data)
            if response != nil && JSON != nil {
                return (T.collection(response: response!, representation: JSON!), nil)
            } else {
                return (nil, serializationError)
            }
        }

        return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: { (request, response, object, error) in
            completionHandler(request, response, object as? [T], error)
        })
    }
}
```

the Club Object Class

```js
final class Club: ResponseCollectionSerializable {

    @objc static func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Club] {
        var clubs = [Club]()

        if let representation = representation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for representationValue in representation {
                let club = Club(JSON: representationValue)
                clubs.append(club)
            }
        }

        return clubs
    }

    let id: String
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let hasVip: Bool
    let location: String

    init(JSON: AnyObject) {
        id = JSON.valueForKeyPath("id") as! String
        name = JSON.valueForKeyPath("name") as! String
        imageUrl = JSON.valueForKeyPath("imageUrl") as! String
        hasVip = JSON.valueForKeyPath("hasVip") as! Bool

        //is OK this implementation?
        location = JSON.valueForKeyPath("location") as! String
    }
}
```

the View Controller Class

```js
class ClubsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    var results: [JSON]? = []
    var clubs: [Club]?

    @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadClubsObjects()
    }

    func loadClubsObjects(){


        var URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.com/v1/clubs")
        var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
        let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)
        request.responseCollection { (request, response, clubs: [Club]?, error) in

        println("request = \(request)")
        println("response = \(response)")
        println("clubs = \(clubs)")
        println("error = \(error)")

            if (json != nil){
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                    self.results = data
                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                }
            }
        }



    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.results?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("clubsObjectCell") as! ClubsTableViewCell
        cell.clubsObject = self.results?[indexPath.row]
        return cell    }

}
```

**the println(clubs) output is:**

```js
   request = <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fd553725870> { URL: https://api.com/v1/clubs }
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fd553439e20> { URL: https://api.com/v1/clubs } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "X-Requested-With, Accept, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, Content-Type, Authorization";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 21 Apr 2015 20:18:07 GMT";
    Etag = "W/\"sEDn5KBhpfpInjAtNsF4gQ==\"";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} })
clubs = Optional([])
error = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, could you change your last lines in the `ViewController` class to be the following?

```
request.responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
    println(request)
    println(response)
    println(json)
    println(error)
}
```

I want to make sure that you have set up your request properly and are getting the response back that you expect. That is certainly half the battle. Once you can verify that, then we can work on the `responseCollection` parsing logic.

Also, what version of Xcode are you using and what version of Alamofire?

---

### UPDATE

The issue you are having is two-fold.

#### Issue 1

First, you are not calling your `responseCollection` method correctly. You should instead call it as follows:

```
request.responseCollection { request, response, clubs: [Club], error in
    println("request = \(request)")
    println("response = \(response)")
    println("clubs = \(clubs)")
    println("error = \(error)")
}
```

This will then call into your `Club` class properly.

#### Issue 2

The second issue is that you are not implementing the `collection` method inside your `Club` object. You're never going to get any clubs without actually iterating through the collection. Something roughly like the following should get you going in the right direction.

```
final class Club: ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    @objc static func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Club] {
        var clubs = [Club]()

        if let representation = representation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for representationValue in representation {
                let club = Club(JSON: representationValue)
                clubs.append(club)
            }
        }

        return clubs
    }

    let id: String
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let hasVip: Bool

    init(JSON: AnyObject) {
        id = JSON.valueForKeyPath("id") as! String
        name = JSON.valueForKeyPath("name") as! String
        imageUrl = JSON.valueForKeyPath("imageUrl") as! String
        hasVip = JSON.valueForKeyPath("hasVip") as! Bool
    }
}
```

Once your `collection` function is actually iterating through all the representation values in the JSON array, you should have more luck.

#### Bonus Points

For bonus points, here are a few other tips to improve your code.

- Switch to using a failable initializer in your `Club` class to guarantee that objects are only created if the JSON is parsed successfully
- Change your implementation inside the `responseCollection` completion closure to actually store the new clubs value and display those clubs in your table view.

> The object returned to the `responseCollection` closure is no longer a JSON AnyObject that you can use with SwiftyJSON, but instead an array of Clubs.

Comment: I've just edited the view controller class, adding the println outputs and I've included the output. The version of Xcode is 6.3 and Alamofire is 1.2

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the issues that I believe you are having. The code may not be exact since I don't have enough sample code of yours to get it to compile, but this should be quite close.

Comment: Regarding 2nd issue, I've implemented the function in the object class as you told me and I've added a location nested property(I'dont know if it's OK implemented). Regarding 1st issue, Ive updated the request.responseCollection (..,..,[Club]?,..) in the view controller class and the println(clubs) output but unfortunately the response it's nil

Comment: but if I change the request by request.responseJSON { request, response, json, error in, the response is not nil but I cannot assign the json("hits") to the club class

Comment: I'm sorry @EdZ, but it's a bit too difficult to assist you here. You are using the very advanced concepts in Alamofire, but lack a solid understanding of the Alamofire basics. I would first try to use SwiftyJSON to parse the response using the `responseJSON` serialization method. Once you have that working properly and have gained some experience with Alamofire, then come back to this approach and hopefully things will make more sense. I can't stress enough that the README in Alamofire is terrific and really breaks things down in a very concise manner.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time @cnoon, I'm going to try another way to acomplish it, and I will complete this thread with the correct solution for you and for all.